# hibernate version is wrong. what happened?

Tags: hibernate, maven

the library(jar packaging) pom's hibernate is below.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

but after deployed in remote repository and the another project using this library, hibernate version is 4.3.11.Final

[image]

what happened?

this is the the another project's dependencies except library.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

---- updated ----

mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[INFO] Building XXXX 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for p6spy:p6spy:jar:2.1.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ XXXX ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[WARNING] Invalid POM for p6spy:p6spy:jar:2.1.4, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] XXXX:XXXX:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:jar:3.7.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-codegen:jar:3.7.0:provided
[INFO] |     +- (com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:3.7.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- com.mysema.codegen:codegen:jar:0.6.8:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.3.1:provided
[INFO] |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] +- com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile (version managed from 1.6.1)
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] \- XXXX:XXXX:jar:1.0.15:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile (version managed from 5.0.4.Final)
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile (version managed from 3.1.3.GA)
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - version managed from 3.1.3.GA; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile (version managed from 5.0.4.Final)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - version managed from 3.1.3.GA; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile - version managed from 5.0.4.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile - version managed from 5.0.4.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     \- (org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.28:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.28:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - version managed from 3.2.1.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-velocity:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile - version managed from 1.8.3; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile - version managed from 1.7.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile - version managed from 1.8; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile - version managed from 1.7.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile - version managed from 1.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - version managed from 3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile - version managed from 1.7.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile - version managed from 1.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO]    |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile - version managed from 2.7.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile - version managed from 1.7.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile - version managed from 1.8; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- (commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile - version managed from 1.6.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile (version managed from 2.4)
[INFO]    +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- (org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.sitemesh:sitemesh:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile (version managed from 1.5.4)
[INFO]    +- p6spy:p6spy:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO]    \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.37:compile
```

Comment: Sounds like the optional hibernate dependencies from query-dsl are taking precedence.  I'd also be weary of whether query-dsl works with ORM5 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependency plugin and its `tree` goal might give you the answer.

Just run

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

in your project and look at all the occurrences of `hibernate-core`. You'll see the reason why it is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your dependency tree, I can see that the last jar (which i guess its the library that you're talking about) is using those hibernate 4.3.11.final

That library's version is 1.0.13. Is this correct? 
Maybe it's version is wrong.